# Can we install only MTLM for certain machines in the team?

Tags: visual-studio, system

Is there a way, where in some testers install only [Microsoft Test and Lab Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015103925/http://geekswithblogs.net/Shadowin/archive/2009/05/13/microsoft-test-and-lab-manager.aspx) (MTLM) instead of installing the whole of [VSTS 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Team_System#Visual_Studio_Team_System_2010)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. MTLM is available a separate, purchasable SKU. It's priced less than VS Ultimate, and includes all of the MTLM functionality.